# R - Number of transactions made by each email id within 1 hour

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows:

```
id  email   Date of purchase    time of purchase
1   abc@gmail.com   11/10/18    12:10 PM
2   abc@gmail.com   11/10/18    12:11 PM
3   abc@gmail.com   11/10/18    12:14 PM
4   abc@gmail.com   11/10/18    1:16 AM
5   abc@gmail.com   11/10/18    2:10 AM
6   def@gmail.com   11/10/18    12:17 PM
7   def@gmail.com   11/10/18    12:24 PM
8   def@gmail.com   11/10/18    1:16 PM
9   ghi@gmail.com   11/10/18    12:10 PM
10  ghi@gmail.com   11/10/18    1:41 PM
11  ghi@gmail.com   11/11/18    1:44 PM
12  ghi@gmail.com   11/11/18    1:56 PM
13  ghi@gmail.com   11/11/18    2:30 AM
14  ghi@gmail.com   11/11/18    2:37 AM
```

I want to calculate the number of transactions made by each email ids within 1 hour. For example, email ids: abc@gmail.com made 3 transactions starting from 11/10/18 12.10 PM to 11/10/18 1.10 PM and made 2 transactions starting from 11/10/18 1.16 PM to 11/10/18 2.16 PM.

My desired output is:

```
email   purchase in 1 hour
abc@gmail.com   3
abc@gmail.com   2
def@gmail.com   3
ghi@gmail.com   1
ghi@gmail.com   1
ghi@gmail.com   2
ghi@gmail.com   2
```

I have no idea how to start doing it in R. My dataset is having 700k rows. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: What is the date format is it month/day/year?

Comment: yes, the date format is month/day/year.

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse);df1 %>% mutate(dateNew = mdy_hm(paste(Dateofpurchase, timeofpurchase))) %>% group_by( hourly = round_date(dateNew, 'hour'), email) %>% summarise(purchaseIn1hour = n())`

Comment: it works. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `round_date` from `lubridate` to round by 'hour' and use it as a grouping variable to get the count of rows

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(dateNew = mdy_hm(paste(Dateofpurchase, timeofpurchase))) %>% 
   group_by( hourly = round_date(dateNew, 'hour'), email) %>% 
   summarise(purchaseIn1hour = n())
```